# Edit .csv file with AWK

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a csv file in which I have to make some changes which you will see in the examples I will put. And I think I can do it with arrays, but I do not know how to structure it. 
Any ideas?

Original File;

```
"1033reto";"V09B";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V09B"
"1033reto";"V010";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V010"
"1033reto";"V015";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V015"
"1033reto";"V08C";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V08C"
"1040reto";"V03D";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1040reto";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
"1050reto";"V03D";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1050reto";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
```

Desired Output:

```
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V09B"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V010"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V015"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V08C"
"1040reto";"V03D";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1040reto";"V03D";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
"1050reto";"V03D";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1050reto";"V03D";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
```

Comment: Could you specify the substitution rules - provided there are any. I do not see any rule that could convert the input to the desired output.
(E.g., if second column equals "V09B", then set the value of the 3rd, 4th, and 5th column to "V010", "V015", "V08C"...)

Comment: As you can see, the original file is ordered by the field 1. Fields from 2 to 7 contain codes that must be added getting a block that is what we will use to replace the fields from 2 to 7 in the original line.

Comment: I think the idea would be to create an array with 6 empty fields, then go read the fields from 2 to 7. If the field is not empty add it to the first position in the array, if is empty ignore it. Thus, for each line of the group. The line group is defined by the first field. But, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Fields 1, 8 and 9 of each line must not be change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

two pass algorithm. no provision whether it will overwrite existing last two columns if there are enough rows...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} 
     NR==FNR{for(i=2;i<=7;i++) if($i!="\"\"") a[$1]=a[$1] FS $i;next}
            {n=split(a[$1],f,FS); for(i=2;i<=n;i++) $i=f[i]}1' csv{,}

"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"";"QVN";"V09B"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"";"QVN";"V010"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"";"QVN";"V015"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"";"QVN";"V08C"
"1040reto";"V03D";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1040reto";"V03D";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
"1050reto";"V03D";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1050reto";"V03D";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
```

UPDATE: in order to guard the last two fields add `if(n>7)n=7;` after the split.

Comment: How do I print the lines to the new file?

Comment: @Criatos `awk '...' file > new_file`

Comment: Nothing prints.
karakfa code is missing something.There is no "print ...;" in the code,

Comment: Nothing prints.
karakfa code is missing something.There is no prints " like (print whatever..;)" in the code.

Comment: @Criatos why don't you even test the code? There is no need for an explicit `print` in awk.

Comment: @Criatos the `1` at the end is for print.

Comment: @karakfa The script don't print anything. I'm writing this.

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==FNR{for(i=2;i<=7;i++) if($i!="\"\"") a[$1]=a[$1] FS $i;next} {n=split(a[$1],f,FS); if(n>7)n=7; for(i=2;i<=n;i++) $i=f[i]}1' QVN_reto_V.csv`

Comment: you're missing `{,}` after filename!  It's required for double pass algorithm. If you don't know what it means or not like it provide the same file twice `awk ... QVN_reto_V.csv QVN_reto_V.csv`