# AWK. Swap fields in a csv file

Tags: csv, awk

The csv file contains nine fields. Fields $ 1, $ 8 and $ 9 must be respected. Add fields $ 2, $ 3, $ 4, $ 5, $ 6 and $ 7 and replace them in lines where the field $1 is repeated. It is hard to describe the rules.

I have to finish this or do something like this.  I need Standalone script.

```
BEGIN{
FS=";"
OFS="";
x="\"\"";
}
{
for(i=2;i<=7;i++) 
if($i!= x)
{
k=match(a[$1], $i);
if (k == 0)
{
a[$1]=a[$1]";"$i;
}
b[$1]=b[$1]"-"$8""FS""$9;
}
END {
for (g in a)
    t=split(a[g], A, ";");
    if (t == 2)
    {
    a[g]=a[g]";"x";"x";"x";"x";"x";";
    }
    if (t == 3)
    {
    a[g]=a[g]";"x";"x";"x";"x";";
    }
    if (t == 4)
    {
    a[g]=a[g]";"x";"x";"x";";
    }
    if (t == 5)
    {
    a[g]=a[g]";"x";"x";";
    }
for (h in b)
    q=split(b[h], B, "-");
for (z=1; z <= q; z++)
    b[h]=B[z];                               
}
}
```

**CSV File:**

```
"1033reto";"V09B";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V09B"
"1033reto";"V010";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V010"
"1033reto";"V015";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V015"
"1033reto";"V08C";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V08C"
"1040reto";"V03D";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1040reto";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
"1050reto";"V03D";"";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1050reto";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
```

**Desired Output**

```
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V09B"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V010"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V015"
"1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";"QVN";"V08C"
"1040reto";"V03D";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1040reto";"V03D";"V01C";"";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
"1050reto";"V03D";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"QVN";"V03D"
"1050reto";"V03D";"V01F";"V07L";"";"";"";"QVN";"V01C"
```

Comment: where is the CSV file?

Comment: It looks like the same input and desired output as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400490/edit-csv-file-with-awk , where you've already accepted an answer. Something different here?

Comment: I do not know how to join array a whith array b in paralell. "1033reto";"V09B";"V010";"V015";"V08C";"";  +  "QVN";"V09B"

Comment: @jas It is true. But I need to do it without-->   }'1 file.csv{,} Can you help?

Comment: Instead of `1` you can put `{ print }`.  Instead of `file.csv{,}` you can put `file.csv file.csv`.

Comment: @jas That could be a solution. Could you help me finish my code ?. I want to learn to do it this way. Although mine is longer code. I believe it's almost finished

Comment: @jas I have already shown to my boss. If I do not finish it my way I will lose face.

Comment: @Craitos try to understand the other solution perhaps you'll learn a thing or two.  It's easier to implement a two pass algorithm, otherwise you have to operate on the whole file or write complicated logic do it blockwise. Also  `filename{,}` is a bash shorthand for writing it twice `filename filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By studying the Karakfa code I managed to find an alternative without double bypass.

```
BEGIN{
FS=";"
x="\"\"";
} 

{
for(i=2;i<=7;i++)
{   
  if($i!= x)
{
  k=match(a[$1], $i);
  if (k == 0)
  {
   a[$1]=a[$1]";"$i;
  }
  }
}
b[$1]=b[$1]"-"$8""FS""$9;

}

END {
for (g in a)
{
    sub("^;","",a[g]);
    t=split(a[g], A, ";");
    for (y=t; y<6; y++)
    {
        a[g]=a[g]";"x;
    }

    mx=split(b[g], B, "-");
    for (i=2; i<=mx; i++)
    {
        print g""FS""a[g]""FS""B[i];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @karakfa I would like to know your opinion about my latest code, it was inspired by yours.